# Fatal Error trying to get number of files in a directory

Tags: java, android

Eventually i want to have an array with the names of all files in a directory. However using this code

```
File f = new File(getFilesDir().toString());
File F[] = f.listFiles();
int i = 0;
for(File entry: F){
    i++;
}

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

To even only count the files doesn't work. When I try to display the value I receive this error.

```
02-07 01:25:47.490 21262-21262/com.mydomain.www.notepad5 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3
       at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:231)
       at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:265)
       at com.mydomain.www.notepad5.MainActivity$3.onDrawerOpened(MainActivity.java:109)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.dispatchOnDrawerOpened(DrawerLayout.java:740)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.updateDrawerState(DrawerLayout.java:700)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$ViewDragCallback.onViewDragStateChanged(DrawerLayout.java:1833)
       at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.setDragState(ViewDragHelper.java:874)
       at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper$2.run(ViewDragHelper.java:335)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 01:25:48.904 21262-21262/com.mydomain.www.notepad5 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21262 SIG: 9
```

Using  `F.length` doesnt work either. I can however display the names of all files.

Comment: That exception is not being raised by the code that you are showing here. Please post the entire stack trace, along with the code referenced in the stack trace.

Comment: You should put comments below the answer they are related to so the person will be notified. Based on the update are you saying that you want to show all the file names in the alert dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage(int)` which is expecting a resource id and you do not have a String resource with the id you are providing. You want to call `AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage(CharSequence)`.

Use `setMessage(String.valueOf(numFiles))` instead to parse the integer into a string so the correct overloaded version of `setMessage` is called.

EDIT:

You updated your exception to use `Toast.makeText` but the same still applies regarding the int being interpreted as a resource id.

EDIT 2:

Here is code that will get all the file names in the directory in an array.

```
File[] files = f.listFiles();
String[] fileNames = new String[files.length];
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    fileNames[i] = files[i].getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void listf(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files) {
File directory = new File(directoryName);

// get all the files from a directory
File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
for (File file : fList) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        files.add(file);
    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
    }
}
```

}